# Transistor Switch Maximum Permissible Resistance

Tags: transistors

I have been learning from a series called "The Great Courses". This is a question that modifies a given example with new numbers. No matter what I do, I cannot reach the correct answer, and the book gives no explanation.

The image is a little messy but all given info is there. Is there something I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: One thing you've done is to divide your voltage by milliamperes instead of Amperes.  (24-0.7)/0.0033

Comment: I don't see how you are supposed to get 5.8 Ohms out of that.

Comment: I got 6.99k, since 500/150=3.33333333333333

Comment: If that's the answer they give, find a better source of study materials.

Comment: The book is absolutely, horribly wrong. Consider that the bulb resistance (assuming the transistor is short-circuited, is 48 ohms. So, since the voltage across the resistor is about the same as the bulb, a 5.8 ohm resistor in that circuit will dissipate about 8 times as much power as the bulb. Your calculations, except for overlooking the fact that Ic is 0.500, rather than 500 (amps rather than mA) are correct, and the resistance required is about 7 kohms.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast thanks for the reply. The books words it as: "Determine the maximum permissible of the resistance (R) in the transistor switch when these changes are made: transistor beta increases to 150, the battery voltage increases to 24V, and the light draws 500mA when fully on"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a Rule of thumb all Transistors are rated at Ic/Ib=10 even if the Vce(sat) is reasonably low at a ratio of 20 or special devices with a ratio of 50, but NEVER use hFE for a switch. Rule of thumb is use 10% of hFE or 10 which ever is higher unless pushing the Ic max limits.

Thus using stead state Tungsten Lamp resistance which drops to <15% R_cold when hot ( ignore that for now)

- Neglect Vce(sat)= 0.7V which you used ok (close as in ballpark close...)
- R_lamp=(24)/500mA = 48 Ω
- Neglect Vbe drop for now = 0.7 (ballpark)
- choose R = 10 * R_load = 480 Ω

Checking

- Ib= (24-0.7)/480 Ω = 55 mA
- so Ic/Ib= 500mA/55= 9.1
- So add 10% ~ 20% and **use 520 Ω ~ 570 Ω** for cool operating transistor
- 500mA *0.7V = 350mW @ 0.250'C/mW for a TO-92 will be 88'C rise above 25'C room which is too hot, so choose a transistor with Vce(sat) =0.3V @ 500mA =150mW

**- RULE OF THUMB using a Common Emitter SWITCH** 
   - (linear load biased from same supply as load.

> **Make Rb/Rc=10**

Comment: My guess the author intended to say 580 Ω instead of 5.8

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I misread, the answer given in 5.8kΩ.

Comment: 5.8k and the transistor will get hot like the bulb with 2V drop where hFE reaches spec in some cases. 1W loss in a tiny part will fry it

Comment: Is it permissible? The question wants the maximum permissible of the resistance (R).

Comment: unless you have Vce(sat) , at rated Ic and rated Ic/Ib ratio AND Pd max, it cannot be computed accurately.. This assumption of I ratio gets the transistor  least lossy so remember Ic/Ib ratios not hFe

Comment: I'm not very far into the book (Lecture 7 of 24,) so maybe those factors are being ignored and the problem simplified. Thanks for the answer.